# How to make constructor or setter based dependency injection?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

The problem is, I have written simple application in spring which gets data from database using jdbctemplate and prints it on site. I want it to be made using dependency injection through constructor or setters(I would like to see both approaches). I was trying to figure it on my own, but I have little experience with Spring and so on I can't make it working. Can anyone provide me with solution, how should it be done using code below?

```
    public class Customer {
    private long id;
    private String firstName, lastName;


    public Customer(long id, String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format(
                "Customer[id=%d, firstName='%s', lastName='%s']",
                id, firstName, lastName);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;


    Customer customer;


    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String hello(Model model, @RequestParam(value="name", required=false, defaultValue="World") String name) {
        model.addAttribute("name", name);
        return "hello";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/getMock")
    public String getMock(Model model) {

        JdbcTemplate mock = Mockito.mock(JdbcTemplate.class);

        List fakeList = new ArrayList<>();
        fakeList.add(new Customer(1l, "sth", "sth2"));



        Mockito.when(mock.query(any(String.class), any(RowMapper.class))).thenReturn(fakeList);

        List<Customer> mockResult = mock.query(
                "SELECT id, first_name, last_name FROM customers",
                (rs, rowNum) -> new Customer(rs.getLong("id"), rs.getString("first_name"), rs.getString("last_name"))
        );

        String result = null;
        for(Customer customer : mockResult) result += (customer.toString() + "<br>");

        model.addAttribute("mockString", result);
        return "hello";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/getDatabase")
    public String getDatabase(Model model) {
        List<Customer> list = jdbcTemplate.query(
                "SELECT id, first_name, last_name FROM customers",
                (rs, rowNum) -> new Customer(rs.getLong("id"), rs.getString("first_name"), rs.getString("last_name"))
        );

        String result = null;
        for (Customer customer : list) result += (customer.toString() + "<br>");
        model.addAttribute("databaseString", result);
        return "hello";
    }
```

Comment: The correct way is to mark the field to inject (in your case `jdbctemplate`) as final, and annotate the constructor with `@Autowired` or `@Inject`. Since  Spring 4.3 if you mark your field as final is not need to use @Autowired

Comment: Thank you for your response. I changed it and it work. 1 more question. How to do the same with Customer class? Since making the same to Customer class doesn't work and I get following error:
 Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.3.5.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project hello-springboot: An exception occurred while running. null: InvocationTargetException: Error creating bean with name 'helloController' defined in file : Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 1 of type [com.hellokoding.springboot.Customer]:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make constructor based dependency injections by following this code snippet:

```
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@Autowired
public HelloController(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate){
    this.jdbcTemplate=jdbcTemplate;
}
```

Or you could do setter based dependency injection as:

```
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@Autowired
public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate){
    this.jdbcTemplate=jdbcTemplate;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for response. How can I achieve the same for Customer class? I tried making similar as this and it didn't work.

Comment: Is your customer class declared as `@Component`?

Comment: be aware that even if you declare the Customer class as @Component this won't work because you initialize the object not the framework. if you want to make it work have a look at https://dzone.com/articles/domain-object-dependency-injection-with-spring

Answer (score 1):

First of All you should add `@component` annotation to your Customer class so this class will be managed by spring. then to inject the customer property in your controller you have 
3 choices:

1)
`@Autowired
Customer customer;`

2)
`@Autowired
 public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }`

3)
`@Autowired
public HelloController(Customer customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }`